# separar string y cargar en lisbox c#

Tags: c#, string, listbox

tengo estos datos separados por `;` en un string `"INSTALL_EFFECT();HAETAE_BLESSING(70);NO_3_SET_EFFECT();MOVE_ADD(2);"`
y quiero cargarlos en un listbox, cual seria la manera mas simple de hacerlo, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes utilizar String.Split no te será nada difícil de seguir, según la documentación [Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split). No obstante mira [ask], y realiza el [tour], que te ayudarán para preguntar en este sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar

```
string cadena = "INSTALL_EFFECT();HAETAE_BLESSING(70);NO_3_SET_EFFECT();MOVE_ADD(2);";
string[] partes = cadena.Split(';');

listBox1.DataSource = partes;
```

Puedes asignar un array de string como datasource del listbox

O si quieres tambien podrias iterar la lista y asignar cada item

```
foreach (string item in partes)
{
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```